# Anybody can help me with the lpirfs package in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to run a linear and nonlinear panel local projection model using the package lpirfs in R. The functions are lp_lin_panel and lp_nl_panel. The goal is to estimate the impulse response functions for the geopolitical risk shock on country inflation rates. The first column of my data is Country. The second column is time. I have 15 countries and I am using quarterly data from 1985-2020. The third column is inflation rate. The fourth column is the gpr index from Iacoviello and Caldara. The fifth column is the lagged gpr. The sixth column is a dummy for inflation rate targeting. The codes I am using are:

```
results_panel <- lp_nl_panel(data_set = data, data_sample = "Full", endog_data = 'Inflation', shock = 'GPR', panel_model = 'within', panel_effect = 'twoways', robust_cov = 'vcovSCC', switching = "IRT", lag_switching = FALSE, gamma = 10, confint = 1, hor = 25)

results_panel_2 <- lp_lin_panel(data_set = data, data_sample = "Full", endog_data = 'Inflation', shock = 'GPR', iv_reg = TRUE, instrum = "GPRIV", panel_model = "within", panel_effect = "twoways", robust_cov = "vcovSCC",confint = 1, hor = 25)
```

For both outputs, I get the same error:

> Error in plm.fit(data, model, effect, random.method, random.models, random.dfcor,  :
> empty model.

I have tried

```
data_1 <- pdata.frame(data, index = "Time")
data_3 <- pdata.frame(data, index = c("Country", "Time"))
```

and both have not worked.

I believe I am setting up the panel data incorrectly, but I am at a loss. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score -1):

You need to order your variables before estimating the Local Projection model. You can do it like this :

`data <- dataset %>% dplyr::select(Country, Time, everything())`

And then you can do your estimations !